# Fetch Data from Wikilocation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, fetch

I try to fetch data from wikilocation.org. As far as i get it, i need to use jsonp to manage this. This basically works with this code:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'http://api.wikilocation.org/articles',
   dataType: "jsonp",
   cache: false,
   jsonp:'onJsonPLoad',
   jsonpcallbackString: "addPoi",
   data: {'lng': newPoi.lon, 'lat': newPoi.lat, 'limit':5, 'radius':100, 'jsonp':'addPoi'}
});
```

My problem is, that i do not want to call another function (addPoi in the snippet) to be able to work with the result. I neet the result directly inside the function, where i make the ajax call. Is that possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work: [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d754b/1/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.wikilocation.org/articles',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'addPoi',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    data: {
        'lng': newPoi.lon,
        'lat': newPoi.lat,
        'limit': 5,
        'radius': 100,
        'jsonp': 'addPoi'
    }
});
```

You have to send wikilocation a function name, and tell jQuery what to expect like you did. Then all you needed to do was add the `success: function (data) { ... }`

Comment: But this will also fire up the 'jsonpCallback'-Function (addPoi) in this case. Why is this line important?

Comment: ...and it looks like the success-function does not fire at all.

Comment: If you have a function addPoi, then it would conflict. JQuery will create the callback function

Comment: Ok, now i got it! I thought, that this function has to exist. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of accessing WikiLocation via JSONP with jQuery is to use the $.getJSON feature along with the jsonp callback parameter as such:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.wikilocation.org/articles?lat=51.500688&lng=-0.124411&limit=1&format=json&jsonp=?", function(data) {
    // do what ever you want with the returned data
    console.log(data);
});
```

From the jQuery docs:

> As of jQuery 1.2, you can load JSON data located on another domain if you specify a JSONP callback.
>   The callback takes the form "example.com?callback=?". jQuery automatically replaces the '?' with a random method name that doesn't clash with the global scope. You do not have to specify the method name yourself.
>
> Note that the site you're trying to call needs to support JSON-P output. The callback parameter might vary depending on the API, for instance Yahoo Pipes requires "_callback=?"
>
> Keep in mind, that lines after this function will be executed before the callback.

And from the WikiLocation docs:

> jsonp (optional) - if you are using the 'json' format, you can choose to supply a JSONP callback via this parameter. This will cause the output to be wrapped inside a callback function (the name of which you supply as the value of the parameter) for cross-domain usage.

Thanks for using WikiLocation - I built it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet and for providing this great API!